# deserialization in jackson of an array of objects

Tags: android, json, jackson

i have a json structure as follows

```
[
  {
    "tag10": "10",
    "tag12": "10",
    "tag13": "10",
    "tag14": "10"
  },
   {
    "tag10": "11",
    "tag12": "11",
    "tag13": "11",
    "tag14": "11"
  },
    {
    "tag10": "12",
    "tag12": "12",
    "tag13": "12",
    "tag14": "12"
  }
]
```

what can be the best way to deserilize and unwrap this array of objects as following can be the bean class

```
public class Abc
{
    private String tag13;

    private String tag14;

    private String tag10;

    private String tag12;

    public String getTag13 ()
    {
        return tag13;
    }

    public void setTag13 (String tag13)
    {
        this.tag13 = tag13;
    }

    public String getTag14 ()
    {
        return tag14;
    }

    public void setTag14 (String tag14)
    {
        this.tag14 = tag14;
    }

    public String getTag10 ()
    {
        return tag10;
    }

    public void setTag10 (String tag10)
    {
        this.tag10 = tag10;
    }

    public String getTag12 ()
    {
        return tag12;
    }

    public void setTag12 (String tag12)
    {
        this.tag12 = tag12;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to deserilize Json:

```
List<Abc> data = new ObjectMapper()
                                    .readValue(
                                            JSONSTRING,
                                            new TypeReference<List<Abc>>() {
                                            });
```

now data have a list of `Abc`s.

Comment: what will be the TypeReference here?? will it be a class which is having a liat of Abc

Comment: It is Refrence of type in `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference.TypeReference` package. you should import `jackson.core` .jar file to your project

Comment: there is a problem with my response when data is present in the response i got JSON Array of JSON objects but when data is not present the i got Empty JSON Object how can i handle this ?